# Process finished with exit code 0 - whats wrong?

Tags: python, pycharm

I made something like this and dont know why wont run:

```
def play_game():

name = (input("Whats your name? "))
age = int(input("How old are you? "))
year = str((2021-age)+100)
print(name+" you will be 100 years old in "+year)
play_again = input("Play again? Yes/No")
if play_again == "Yes":
    play_again = True
else:
    play_again = False
if play_again:
    play_game()
```

Comment: One you fix the indentation (which is probably due to the fact that you didn't use the code insertion in the question edit box) the above code has no problem (though it is too verbose). It also contains no executable statements (it merely defines the function). How are you calling this function?

Comment: So what should I do to make it work?

Comment: Exit code 0 means everything was fine.

Comment: You should call your function... `play_gmae()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code only declares the function, try to add `play_game()` outside of the function itself.

Comment: @MBD If someone's answer solves your problem, consider marking it as "accepted" (via the check mark next to the question).

Answer (score 1):

```
def play_game():

    name = (input("Whats your name? "))
    age = int(input("How old are you? "))
    year = str((2021-age)+100)
    print(name+" you will be 100 years old in "+year)
    play_again = input("Play again? Yes/No")

    if play_again == "Yes":
        return True
    else:
        return False


play_game()
if play_game() == True:
    play_game()
```

Comment: You will run the function twice even if the user had inputted `No` the first time... And anyway you allow at most three runs of the game while the original code is unlimited

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other points raised here, remember that Python requires proper indentation.  So the code should be indented as follows:

```
def play_game():
     name = (input("Whats your name? "))
     age = int(input("How old are you? "))
     year = str((2021-age)+100)
     print(name+" you will be 100 years old in "+year)
     play_again = input("Play again? Yes/No")
     if play_again == "Yes":
          play_again = True
     else:
          play_again = False
     return play_again  # you either have to create a global variable or you have to return play_again otherwise this is meaningless

# This both calls the function but also stores the value
# returned from the function
returnedValue = play_game() 
while returnedValue:
    returnedValue = play_game()
```

Comment: `returnedValue = play_game` just assigns `returnedValue` to point to the function. Your added code doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: @CrazyChucky Assuming you down-voted, please check the edit

Comment: @Rasputin In general it is better to avoid expressions like *"as the point above/below"* in this site as the pages are dynamic and what might seem to you above might seem below to someone else and it might just create confusion. It is better to write answers that are "stand-alone", or when counting on external sources, link properly so it is clear what you are referring to